# Python printing format in a for loop

Tags: python

```
*if menuInput == '1':
     print("")
     encryptString = input("Please enter string to encrypt:")
     print("")
     offSetValue = int(input("Please enter offset value (1-94):"))
     print("")
 
     for character in encryptString:
         x = ord(character)
         y = x + offSetValue
         z = chr(y)      
         print("Encrypted string:") 
         print(z)*
```

I want the string that has been encrypted to be outputted in this format:

Encrypted string:

```
abcde
```

but it comes out in this format:

```
Encrypted string: 
a
Encrypted string: 
b
Encrypted string: 
c
Encrypted string: 
d
```

I've tried using end and sep but they don't help.

Comment: the way it currently comes out as is: "Encrypted string" and then a new line then "a" and so on for every character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
print("")
encryptString = input("Please enter string to encrypt:")
print("")
offSetValue = int(input("Please enter offset value (1-94):"))
print("")

print("Encrypted string:") 
for character in encryptString:
    x = ord(character)
    y = x + offSetValue
    z = chr(y)      
    print(z, end="")

print()
```

You want `print("Encrypted string:")` before the loop and use `end` instead of `sep`. `sep` is used to separate multiple arguments in the print. `end` is the terminating character(s) added to the end of what is printed. Here we terminate with the empty string. The default for `end` is the newline character, `\n`. That is why you saw everything printed on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

By using fernet, it allows you to encrypt messages more securely than shifting the position of characters in the string.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
if menuInput == '1':
    print()
    encryptString = input("Please enter string to encrypt:")
    print()
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    encryptedString = fernet.encrypt(encryptString.encode())
    print("Encrypted string:", encryptedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.

```
if menuInput == '1':
 print("")
 encryptString = input("Please enter string to encrypt:")
 print("")
 offSetValue = int(input("Please enter offset value (1-94):"))
 print("")

 print("Encrypted string:") 
 for character in encryptString:
     x = ord(character)
     y = x + offSetValue
     z = chr(y)      
     print(z, end='')
```